# VBA Nested loops in tabular data

Tags: vba, excel

I've had a pretty thorough search but I'm still struggling with this problem. Essentially, I have a list of various titles, each of which has 10 variables corresponding, which may or may not have data points.

[image: Table]

I'd like to loop through the first column, with a nested loop going through each row to count and record the number of populated data points in each. Mostly I'm not sure how to reference cells in the second loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far, keep in mind SO is not a coding service, also you might just use a `=COUNTIF` formula in column L

Answer (score 1):

I dont really understand your ultimate goal however i hope the code below will help you to go to the right direction.

As far as i understand i wrote a code that COUNT how many cells for each row where there s data.

I am not really sure if it is what you want but let me know and i will edit my code to your requirement.

Option Explicit

```
Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, c As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") '  Change the name of your worksheet

Lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' Find the las row

With ws

        For i = 1 To Lastrow 'Start at row 1 until the last row

            c = 0

                For j = 2 To 11 ' 10 Variables (until the column "L")
                        If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, j)) Then c = c + 1  ' Count and record the number of populated data points in each columns
                Next j

            .Cells(i, 12).Value = c 'Past the result in column "L"

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```